# The session expiration date cannot be changed with Azure AD B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

- List item

I am using an Azure AD B2C custom policy. When using a custom policy session, the default session expiration time is 86,400 seconds. I added the SessionExpiryType and SessionExpiryInSeconds tags to the UserJourneyBehaviors tag of the custom policy to change the session expiration time to 900 seconds. Specifically, I added the following tags and values.

```
 <UserJourneyBehaviors>  
 <SessionExpiryType>Absolute</SessionExpiryType>
 <SessionExpiryInSeconds>900</SessionExpiryInSeconds>
 </UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

I made the above changes and verified the operation, but the session expiration time remained at 86,400 seconds. What should I do to change the session expiration time?

Comment: How did you conclude that "but the session expiration time remained at 86,400 seconds"?

Comment: ensure that the policy file is correctly formatted, that the session expiration time is not being overridden, and verify the changes in the Azure portal. If the issue persists, consider using the Azure AD B2C portal to make changes to the policy.